# Machine Learning using Python: how do I use matplotlib to plot the SVM?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, svm

I'm new to machine learning (using python). I referred to a few books, but I am not able to figure out how to plot the SVM using matplotlib.

Please help me to plot the following:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
features_train=[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]]
label_train=[1,2,3]
features_test=[[1,2],[2,1]]
clf=SVC()
clf.fit(x,y)
pred=clf.predict(features_test)
print(pred)
```

Comment: What did you try and what is the problem your are facing ?

Comment: i tried this.... plt.scatter(fearures_train,label_train). This is working fine when both the list is of 1 dimension. But when I am keeping the features_train as 2D its throwing error. Basically i just want to know is there any way to plot it by using ONLY matplotlib?

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below and read the comments. It will help you as a tyro. For more detail you may catch up this link [mlExtend](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/) which could help in getting the better insight of **SVM** having `matplotlib` under it's hood.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd # For more detail catch up the link below
from sklearn import svm
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Create arbitrary dataset for example
df = pd.DataFrame({'Planned_End': np.random.uniform(low=-5, high=5, size=50),
               'Actual_End':  np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=50),
               'Late':        np.random.random_integers(low=0,  high=2, size=50)}
)

# Fit Support Vector Machine Classifier
X = df[['Planned_End', 'Actual_End']]
y = df['Late']

clf = svm.SVC(decision_function_shape='ovo')
clf.fit(X.values, y.values) 

# Plot Decision Region using mlxtend's awesome plotting function
plot_decision_regions(X=X.values, 
                  y=y.values,
                  clf=clf, 
                  legend=2)

# Update plot object with X/Y axis labels and Figure Title
plt.xlabel(X.columns[0], size=14)
plt.ylabel(X.columns[1], size=14)
plt.title('SVM Decision Region Boundary', size=16)
```

However, if you are unaware of pandas you could follow up this link:
http://pandas.pydata.org/ for docs. Hope it works

Comment: thanx. I was not knowing about this "mlxtend" module. Its quite interesting. But can we plot without using mlxtend and using ONLY matplotlib?

Comment: Check this link out:https://gist.github.com/glamp/4365631                            
 It would not be so flexible as the answer above though but give it a try

Comment: @RishiAnand Was the answer helpful?

Comment: Could you add an example image to your answer?

Comment: Sir(@Martin Thoma) I have embedded a link which provide a better insight of the situation(thanks to Raschka, Sebastian) with many example images.